# How to replace a character in a string using index in clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to replace a character in a string using index. How to do that? Or is there any other way of accessing it?

Comment: please post your code / your tries here

Comment: new to stackoverflow, will do from next time on. Thanks!]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like almost everything commonly used in Clojure, strings are immutable, so you need to create a new string with the new character in place of the old at the desired location:

```
(defn replace-at [s idx replacement]
  (str (subs s 0 idx) replacement (subs s (inc idx))))

> (replace-at "012345" 2 "x")
01x345
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me a lot!

Comment: The same applies in Java, which has immutable strings too.

Answer (score 1):

`Strings` are immutable, but `StringBuilders`s are not, so you could leverage that:

```clj
(defn set-char-at [^String s idx ch]
  (str (doto (StringBuilder. s) (.setCharAt idx ch))))
(set-char-at "foobar" 2 \x) ;;=> "foxbar"
```